# Unsure about this usage of the word まで

Tags: word-usage, particle-まで

I was doing some N4 practice questions and came across this sentence

先生に すっかり ごちそうになって おみやげ まで いただいてしまいました。

I'm not sure what まで is supposed to mean in this context?

My general understanding of the sentence's meaning is 'I was treated very well by my teacher and I received some omiyage from them' but I can't see how まで plays into all this.

If anyone knows if this is a different usage of まで that I haven't learnt yet that would be great!

Comment: Have you looked up まで ?　What does your dictionary say?　https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/迄/#je-71830  See definition #4

Comment: The only uses of まで I am familiar with are when saying 'until' in reference to a location or point or period in time

e.g. かいぎは１０じから５じまでです。 - the meeting is from 10 till 5.

東京から大阪まではどのぐらいかかりますか。- how long does it take from tokyo to nagoya?

but I can't see how either of these uses fits in to the example I posted.

Comment: I think I understand it from the explanation of まで being an intensifier. i.e. I was treated well by my teacher and I _even_ received a gift from them. 

Thank you.